# In how many ways can $5$ pairs of shoes with distinct colours be arranged in a row subject to the stated conditions?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

"5 pairs of shoes with distinct colours are to be arranged in a row. In how many ways can they be arranged if all the left shoes are together and all the right shoes are together. Shoes of the same colour cannot be next to each other".

I separated the shoes into 2 groups left and right shoes respectively. Then, i realised you can shuffle each shoe in both groups 5! so my workings turned out to be 2! x 5! x 5! = 28800.

My problem is right now whenever a shoe from the left group is at the end and is the same colour as the first shoe from the right group. I dont know how to take care of that scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have all the possible combinations of shoes, I would just subtract the combinations that are not wanted. "Not wanted" means: two of the same color in the middle are next to each other. If you start with the shoe on the left side: you have $5!$ possible permutations. For the shoes on the right you have already a given "first position" shoe (it has to have the same color as the last left one). So you end up with $4!$ combinations, as the other $4$ can be in any order. That means that there are
$2! \times 5! \times 5! - 2! \times 5! \times 4! = 23040$ combinations.

Comment: I think the calculation
$$2! \times 5! \times 5! - 2! \times 5! \times 4! = 5760 $$
is mistaken.

Comment: I read the answer of "true blue anil" and I can't figure out why my answer is so different from his answer. For me, I think that I am right, but also I do not want so say, that my answer is 100% correct... maybe you can spot my mistake?

Comment: $$2! \times 5! \times 5! - 2! \times 5! \times 4! = 23040 $$
Check it.

Your reasoning is correct.

Comment: Oh wow! I messed up with the windows calculator! Thank you, I will change it! (This is embarassing......)

Comment: yup, i can understand the logic behind this ty

Comment: @NigelTan if that helped you, I would be happy if you marked my reply as answer! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

- Choose one left, one right from  different pairs, and arrange them as L-R or R-L as dividers, thus $5*4*2 =40$ ways for dividers
- Now just multiply by $4!4!$  for the remaining pairs to get $40*4!4!=23040$ total ways

Comment: hey, what do u mean by dividers?

Comment: @Nigel Tan: The middle, where we ensure that left and right aren't. from the same pair.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate approach:

By symmetry, the number of ways with the left-foot shoes on the left equals the number of ways with the left-foot shoes on the right.  So, reserve the factor of $~(2),~$ and then assume, without loss of generality, that the left-foot shoes come first.

The left-shoes can be permuted in $~(5!)~$ ways.

For any such arrangement, there will be only $~4~$ choices, rather than $~5~$ choices, for the first right- shoe, since the right-shoe of the same color as the last left-shoe can not be the first right-shoe.

Then, after the $~(4)~$ choices are made for the first right-shoe, there are $~(4!)~$ ways of permuting the remaining right-shoes.

So, the final computation is

$$2 \times 5! \times 4 \times 4! = 23040.$$

Answer (score 0):

You can choose a pair of shoes first, so there are 8 shoes, 4 on the left, 4 on the right, and the left and the right can be swapped. There are five pairs of shoes so that should be 5* 2* 4!*4!
Then Subtract this from 28,800
We get 23040

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer would be clearer if you specified that you were subtracting the number of arrangements in which a left shoe and a right shoe from the same pair are in adjacent positions from the total number of arrangements in which all the left shoes are together and all the right shoes are together.